# Customize azure webjob schedule timing for different users

Tags: azure, customization, scheduler, azure-webjobs

Currently I'm having azure webjob which is triggered by azure scheduler every 2 hours statically.But I need to make schedule time dynamic based each user configuration in my website.since functionality is same for all user except schedule execution time I can't go for new webjobs.I looked into azure queues with parameters cron values but I don't have any clue how to implement the above case.

Please explain how to Customize azure webjob schedule timing for different users.

Comment: Can you describe your scenario in more details?

Comment: Yes We need more information about what you try to achive, there coulb be several approaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as 1 minute granularity is fine (and you have your site set to Always On), I would use the WebJobs SDK Extension TimerTrigger instead of a scheduled webjob.

Then you can do the following:

1. Have a table or data storage somewhere that tracks when the code was last run for a user and setup when it needs to run again
2. Set the TimerTrigger that checks the data store in #1 to run every minute and see if anything needs to run, if so - then throw a message in a queue and return
3. Have another function that listens to that queue the timer trigger just threw a message in with a QueueTrigger and do whatever processing you are currently doing now.

That should allow for your users to have their own schedule and to have the code triggered by those schedules.

**Update:**
Here is a simple example of a producer/consumer model using the Timer and Queue triggers:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ProducerConsumer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

        config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        config.UseTimers();

        var host = new JobHost(config);
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
}

public static class Functions
{
    public static int counter = 0;

    // Create a new message on the "orders" queue every 10 seconds
    public static void Producer(
        [TimerTrigger("00:00:10", RunOnStartup=true)] TimerInfo timer,
        [Queue("orders")] out string messageCount,
        TextWriter log)
    {
        messageCount = "message" + counter++;

        log.WriteLine("messsage: " + messageCount);
    }

    // Watch the "orders" queue for messages, and when one is found save it to blob storage
    public static void Consumer(
        [QueueTrigger("orders")] string message,
        [Blob("orders/order.txt")] out string order,
        TextWriter log)
    {
        order = message;

        log.WriteLine("Received " + message);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks.This is which I needed.It would be nice value added stuff if you include some more info on timertrigger and queue trigger.Anyhow thanks for the idea.it should work in my case.

Comment: I updated the answer to include a sample of the timer and queue triggers.  I also created a hands on lab that covered the queue and other triggers in april and will have more information for you than i can put in here.  the code and the step by step walkthrough is on github at: https://github.com/JasonHaley/BostonAzureBootcamp2016Material  the HOL-WebJobs/End/OrderProcessingJob is the code and the doc is the AzureBootCampWebJobsHOL.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Azure scheduler won't be able to trigger based on the user.

Probably you must need a continuous running web job, which needs to run based on the user specific schedule. you must need to store the user specific schedule in a table/configuration/file. Read those schedule and run the job only if the schedule condition is met. Or you can use service bus to trigger the web job. your service bus must trigger based the user schedule.